# What does "$a\phi + b\nabla \phi \dot{} \mathbf{n} $ on the boundary" mean? Where n is a unit vector.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What does "$a\phi + b\nabla \phi \dot{} \mathbf{n} $ on the boundary" mean? Where $\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector. We are speaking in the context of an eigenvalue problem (e.g. Vibrating rectangular membrane).

Comment: Do you want the square really or is it just a gradient?
If it is a gradient, most commonly a,b have opposite signs. In this case this is a boundary condition of the Newton's Law of Cooling type: you put the system in contact with another system with some finite "conductivity" and they exchange "material" based on the differences in the amounts of "material". Look up Robin boundary conditions for more such examples.

Answer (score 0):

An example of how this can come up is something like:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\Delta T \quad x \in \Omega \\
\nabla T \cdot n = k(T-T_0) \quad x \in \partial \Omega$$

which is of your form with $b=1,a=-k$. Here for physical reasons $k$ is a positive constant. This is a heat equation where the boundary condition represents thermal contact with an ideal heat reservoir at temperature $T_0$. In this case heat leaves the domain if $T>T_0$ and enters it if $T<T_0$. If $T$ is spatially homogeneous then this reduces to Newton's Law of Cooling.

Such boundary conditions involving a linear combination of the normal part of the gradient and the function value, when both coefficients are nonzero, are called Robin conditions. They are fairly common in applications (because they give a way of representing this "contact" between domains through a boundary).